# Move certain files with cmd

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have many files e.g. 1000 in count with different name that I have a list of it. If I want to move certain files (suppose 400 in count) to any directory, how can I do this?

The problem is the files have no extension to them, they are without file extension, so I cannot sort them accordingly and then move them.

Is there any command through which I put those 400 files name in CMD along with some 'move' command and move them to any particular folder or any batch_code through which I just put as many file name that I want to move and move them to particular folder!

Comment: how can `cmd` identify the 400/1000 files? How do you do this?

Comment: cmd will not identify by itself, i will give the name of those 400 files to be moved to particular location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming, you have the 400 *files to move* in a list, this should work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filelist.txt) do move "%%~a" "destination folder"
```

Comment: ok, so in the 'fileslist.txt' I should place the file name separated by a line, right ?